# Different answers on a Conditional Density problem

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-probability

Here's a joint density function for you:

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac23(x+2y): &0\le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1 \\
0: &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

I want to calculate the probability that $X + Y \gt 1$, given that $|X-Y| = 0.2$. The solution provided in my textbook is as follows:

$P(X+Y>1\,\mid\, |X-Y|=0.2) = \cfrac{P(X+Y>1 \bigcap |X-Y| = 0.2)}{P(|X-Y|=0.2)} = \cfrac{\int_{0.6}^1(x+2(x-0.2)dx + \int_{0.4}^{0.8}(3x-0.4)dx}{\int_{0.2}^1(x+2(x-0.2)dx + \int_0^{0.8}(3x-0.4)dx}=0.7$

Fine. This involves integrating over a line, which I had to remind myself how to do. Not the prettiest solution, but maybe that's called for. My question to you is why this solution of mine produces a wrong answer:

$P(X+Y>1\,\mid\,|X-Y|=0.2)=P(X+Y>1\,\mid\, X-Y = 0.2) +P(X+Y>1\,\mid\, X-Y=-0.2)=P(Y>1-X\,\mid\, X=0.2+Y)+P(Y>1-X\,\mid\, X=-0.2+Y)=P(Y>1-0.2-Y)+P(Y>1+0.2-Y)=P(2Y>0.8)+P(2Y>1.2)=P(Y>0.4)+P(Y>0.6)$

So now I have to find my marginal density function for Y,

$f_Y(y) = \int_0^1(\frac23x+\frac43y)dx = \begin{cases}
\frac13+\frac43y: &0\le y \le 1 \\
0: &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Then

$P(Y>0.4) + P(Y>0.6) = \int_{0.4}^1(\frac13+\frac43y)dy + \int_{0.6}^1(\frac13+\frac43y)dy = 0.76 + 0.56 = 1.32$

Perhaps you can see why I am not satisfied with such an answer! Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Doesn't the event $|X-Y|=0.2$ have probability 0, since we're talking about continuous RV?

Comment: You can have conditional distributions like $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ where you calculate the probability of $a\le Y\le b$ based on the event $X=x$. So although I agree with your instinct, somehow in conditional density world we don't mind the conditional event "technically" having probability $0$.

Comment: Also I check textbook calculations with the help of conditional pdf and also got $0.7$. The conditional pdf is $$f_{X+Y\mid\, |X-Y|}(u\mid 0.2) = \frac58 u I(0.2<u<1.8)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wrong equality is 
$$
P(X+Y>1\,\mid\,|X-Y|=0.2)=P(X+Y>1\,\mid\, X-Y = 0.2) +P(X+Y>1\,\mid\, X-Y=-0.2).
$$
If $B=B_1\cup B_2$ where $B_1,B_2$ are disjoint, it is not true that 
$$
\mathbb P(A \mid B) = \mathbb P(A \mid B_1)+\mathbb P(A \mid B_2).
$$
And it is true that 
$$
\mathbb P(A \mid B) = \frac{\mathbb P(A \cap B_1)+\mathbb P(A \cap B_2)}{\mathbb P(B_1)+\mathbb P(B_2)}.
$$

Next, the equality 
$$
P(Y>1-X\mid X=0.2+Y)+P(Y>1-X\mid X=-0.2+Y)=P(Y>1-0.2-Y)+P(Y>1+0.2-Y)
$$
in your solution is wrong too. Right equality should be 
$$
P(Y>1-X\mid X=0.2+Y)+P(Y>1-X\mid X=-0.2+Y)=P(Y>1-0.2-Y\mid X=0.2+Y)+P(Y>1+0.2-Y\mid X=-0.2+Y).
$$
$Y$ is not independent of $X-Y$, so we cannot remove condition.

Comment: Two years later and I had to come back to this as I once again inappropriately asserted that $\mathrm P(A) = \mathrm P(A|B) + \mathrm P(A|B^C)$. If you have any material on this that would help me kick this intuition please share.

Comment: @jeremy909 You need to make a clear distinction between the concepts of co-occurrence probability and conditional probability. Because the equality $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$ is true, and the equality $P(A) = P(A|B) +  P(A|B^C)$ is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I agree. For example:
$A = 1\mathrm d6 \text{ rolls a } 2, B = 1\mathrm d6 \text{ rolls an even number}$